# How do I removed files from heroku public/assets folder

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I tried creating .gzip files for all my font files and then loaded everything into heroku.

After precompiling and fingerprinting, I now see two of each  (normal and bad gzip version).  This method of compressing the font files was not correct and I now want to delete all the .gz extensions for the font files.  I have removed them from my local drive, but they still exist in production.

How do I permanently remove them from the heroku server in public/assets?

rm filename doesn't remove it permanently.

NORMAL FILES 
    FontAwesome-8b64729a70fdae39b0f8fabf309c3954.otf
    fontawesome-webfont-3b53a5ecdb9473016ee097f74f4f16c0.eot
    fontawesome-webfont-51b69bdec08f19b3142dcd085ba6238a.svg  
    fontawesome-webfont-69b0f4550dbb8738458172d11513538d.ttf  
    fontawesome-webfont-9a3b8f90662fe9149f07a059f1a4c782.woff

GZIPPED 
    FontAwesome.otf-182c2d3c0b929660ff9836203537be50.gz
    fontawesome-webfont.eot-e0b71075aeaa5e6bae453b1422158330.gz 
 
    fontawesome-webfont.svg-853c40f93871de94d73f1feffc6dc3f6.gz
    fontawesome-webfont.ttf-a30218956b0387e9bb423398024bdfe6.gz
    fontawesome-webfont.woff-c2cbac258285338c9f867d363373ca39.gz

Answer (score 2):

I think Git can be helpful for this. You need to push the code with nothing in the public folder or it will be better if you push the code the with the things you want in the public folder so it'll basically replace the previous content.

Comment: sorry I don't understand.  So I should remove everything from my app/aseets folder locally and then push up to heroku.

Comment: you want to remove from public folder right? if yes, then remove all the files from the public/assets folder and then again do precompile and then push it to heroku.
1) Remove all files from `public/assets`
2) Precompile again
3) git add .
4) git commit
5) git push
6) git push heroku master
This will help you replacing all the old files with the new ones.